# Change the Controller when switch technology

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, model-view-controller

Right now I use the **Eclipse** with **Scene Builder**.
I've built the code using an **MVC**.
I want to change the **Scene Builder** but I can't understand if I need to change my **controller**.

I can't find anywhere the web if it's necessary to change the Controller if a technology is changed (in this case: **Scene Builder**).

Comment: What do you mean by "change the Scene Builder"? And why does that mean you might need to change your controller? Scene Builder is simply a [WYSIWYG editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) for FXML files. If there's another application for this (I don't know of one) it will do the same thing. Otherwise you can edit the FXML file directly.

Comment: Different versions of SceneBuilder should be able to deal with the same fxmls/controllers (With some restrictions for newer node types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web and testing myself, I have found out that if you I change the **technology**, the controller is also has to be change. for example: Switching from Scene Builder to developing to mobile.

Comment: I think there is a big misunderstanding about what you consider a "technology". You seem to equate SceneBuilder with JavaFX in general. So, if switching technology means abandoning JavaFX then yes, you have to create a replacement for your controller. If you just abondon SceneBuilder and decide to create your FXML-files with some other tool or just an editor then you do not have to change your controller because the controller does not know anything about SceneBuilder anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to change anything. SceneBuilder just creates FXML files which you could also create by hand if you like to.

Comment: Basically any other program I use instead of SceneBuilder will make only FXML files?

Comment: I don't know any other program but the ones I do know do create FXML files, e.g.  e(fx)clipse.

Comment: This is not true, I can use another technology without changing my controller.

Comment: What is not true?

Comment: Your answer, if you change the technology - you will have to change the controller as well, see my answer